# Aligning a section of text to the bottom left corner of a two column page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align, framed

I am trying to align a chunk of text to the bottom left corner of a two-column document. The chunk of text should fill the width of the left column and should flow upwards for as much space as needed. The two-column format should overflow from the first column to the next one as it reaches the chunk of text. I am using "framed" and "shaded" to put the text into a separate box but this seems to just flow with the normal text.

The idea behind this is to include a declaration on the front of a paper for college submission. The location is important.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,english]{article}   

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\definecolor{frameborder}{rgb}{0,0,0}

\begin{document}
    \twocolumn
    \section{Introduction}
        \lipsum[3-5]

        \begin{shaded*}
              It is hereby declared that this report is entirely my own work, unless otherwise stated, and that all sources of information have been properly acknowledged and referenced. It is also declared that this report has not previously been submitted, in whole or in part, as part fulfilment of any module assessment requirement.\\ \\

              Signed: \makebox[1.1in]{\hrulefill} \hfill Date: \makebox[0.7in]{\hrulefill} \\
        \end{shaded*}

        \lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @dexteritas I have added sample code. You will see that the grey box simply sits where it comes in the text. I want to hard align it to the bottom left of the first sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would suffice, but I used a float environment (in this case `figure`, though a new `float` type could be created instead) with the `[b]` specifier to place it at the bottom of the 1st column.  However, I found that the `shaded` environment interfered with that approach and so I replaced `shaded` with a `\colorbox{\parbox{}{}}` instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,english]{article}   

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\definecolor{frameborder}{rgb}{0,0,0}

\begin{document}
    \twocolumn
    \section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[b]
\colorbox{shadecolor}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{%
  It is hereby declared that this report is entirely my own 
  work, unless otherwise stated, and that all sources of information 
  have been properly acknowledged and referenced. It is also declared 
  that this report has not previously been submitted, in whole or in 
  part, as part fulfilment of any module assessment requirement.\bigskip

              Signed: \makebox[.8in]{\hrulefill} \hfill Date: \makebox[0.5in]{\hrulefill}% 
        }}
\end{figure}
        \lipsum[3-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Steven. Your solution seems to be right but my version of LaTeX running through TexStudio is only printing a small blank space where it thinks the figure should go? Once this is figured this out I will mark your solution as correct. Have you any ideas?

Comment: @DeeCee I can't imagine what the issue is.  For diagnosis, you could try a simpler `figure` environment, such as `\begin{figure}[b]\fbox{TESTING}\end{figure}` to see if you can get it to generate anything in the lower left corner.  If so, then slowly build your way back to the `\colorbox` to see where the failure occurs.

Comment: Hi Steven. I used \twocolumn in my MWE but used multicols in my actual project. Apparently multicols interferes with figures. Thanks for your help Steven!